# Queue Select Range between specific entries

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am creating a serial protocol parser and would like some help filtering the queue data.  I've created serial parsers in the past (using c/c++), but this time I am using C# which i am omittedly a novice.

The serial protocol adheres to the following format:

```
byte StartByte  (SOH = 0x01)
byte MsgCode
byte PayloadLength
byte[] Payload
byte StopByte (EOT = 0x04)
```

I have a the following queue definition:

```
Queue<byte> rxByteQueue = new Queue<byte>(64);
```

As bytes are received from the Serial Port, they are added to the rxByteQueue.

I am try to accomplish the following:

1. Select all bytes between (and including) the StartByte and StopByte.

   - This may or may not include nested entries
2. Check the validity of the serial packet on each entry
3. If the entry is valid, the corresponding range of bytes will be removed from the queue

I can handle items #2 and #3, but feel like there is probably a nifty way to accomplish #1 using LINQ.

Comment: Can you handle #1 without LINQ? It may be easier to translate your current code then write it from scratch.

Comment: I could do that, but was hoping to pickup some new techniques.  LINQ isn't required, i'm open to anything that doesn't require the amount of code that I would have to port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest way, but it does not work with nested entries.

```
var message = rxByteQueue.SkipWhile(x => x != 0x01)
                         .TakeWhile(x => x != 0x04)
                         .Concat(new byte[] { 0x04 });
```

Btw. how does nested entry looks like?

Comment: 'code'
Thanks, that definitely helps.  An example of "nested" entry would be something like this:

Message
Start:   0x01
Code:    0xAA
Length:  0x04
Payload: 0x02,0x04,0xFF,0xFF
Stop:    0x04

0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
0x01,0xAA,0x04,0x02,0x04,0xFF,0xFF,0x04


The intent would be to select bytes 0 to 7, but because 0x04 is part of the payload it may select bytes 0 to 4

Comment: How do you know if `0x04` is not a stop byte if it's inside payload part of the message?